# fred api Python -

Tags: python

Reading through some of the code to initialize the Fred class, I was wondering what the point of the api_key / self.api_key interaction below.  It seems like api_key is referencing the class definition, which there is none...  See the two commented sections.  Shouldn't it just be something like if `self.api_key is not none: self.api_key=api_key`

```
  class Fred(object):
    earliest_realtime_start = '1776-07-04'
    latest_realtime_end = '9999-12-31'
    nan_char = '.'
    max_results_per_request = 1000

    def __init__(self,
                 api_key=None,
                 api_key_file=None):
        """
        Initialize the Fred class that provides useful functions to query the Fred dataset. You need to specify a valid
        API key in one of 3 ways: pass the string via api_key, or set api_key_file to a file with the api key in the
        first line, or set the environment variable 'FRED_API_KEY' to the value of your api key. You can sign up for a
        free api key on the Fred website at http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/
        """
        self.api_key = None #why? already is none
        if api_key is not None: #what is this for? 
            self.api_key = api_key
        elif api_key_file is not None:
            f = open(api_key_file, 'r')
            self.api_key = f.readline().strip()
            f.close()
        else:
            self.api_key = os.environ.get('FRED_API_KEY')
        self.root_url = 'https://api.stlouisfed.org/fred'

        if self.api_key is None:
            import textwrap
            raise ValueError(textwrap.dedent("""\
                    You need to set a valid API key. You can set it in 3 ways:
                    pass the string with api_key, or set api_key_file to a
                    file with the api key in the first line, or set the
                    environment variable 'FRED_API_KEY' to the value of your
                    api key. You can sign up for a free api key on the Fred
                    website at http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/"""))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.**

```
self.api_key = None #why? already is none
```

No, it's not None: the `api_key` attribute of this Fred instance does not exist yet. `api_key` and `self.api_key` are not the same variable. So writing `self.api_key = None` ensures this attribute exists.

**2.**

```
if api_key is not None: #what is this for?
```

`api_key` is a [keyword argument](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=keyword%20argument#keyword-arguments):

```
def __init__(self,
                 api_key=None,
                 api_key_file=None):
```

So when a new Fred instance is created, it's possible to write `Fred(api_key='something')`. In this case, `api_key` will contain `'something'` from the start of `__init__()`. But it's also possible to write `Fred()` and `api_key` will contain, by default, `None` from the start of `__init__()`

If the user has not entered a value for the `api_key` argument, the function will check the same for a possible `api_key_file` argument. If nothing was entered, it will try to retrieve it from an environment variable. If it still can't get any value, it raises an exception.

**3.** So if you start the function writing:

```
if self.api_key is not none: self.api_key=api_key
```

You will probably get an `AttributeError` (because `self.api_key` does not exist yet).

Comment: I guess what I meant was that the first 3 lines seem like they could be remove and just replaced with self.api_key = api_key, then it's already initialized to None and you don't need the following two checks.  Right?

Comment: That's not what you wrote in your question, but replacing the two first lines by `self.api_key=api_key` would do. The following checks would still have to be made: say someone writes `Fred(api_key_file="some_path")`, then you would have `self.api_key` set to `None` and that's all. Same for `Fred()` (the environment variable should be retrieved then).